# Fixing "White Screen of Death"/Broken Wordpress site without accessing FTP?

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I'm working on a site via EASYPRESS, a Canadian hosting service connected to EasyDNS. I can't access my FTP information. I'm wondering if it's possible to fix the infamous "white screen of death" that occurs after breaking a Wordpress site without FTP access. I broke functions.php and need to access it to remove the bad code. I only have access to my DNS at this point. Any help appreciated.

Comment: can u able to access wordpress admin panel?

Comment: I would say that you really have a problem here. Unfortunately you will need to get ftp access directly or through your cpanel. You are a naughty girl making changes to your code via the code editor in the back end, one small change to your code can break your site like now. You should really think about a local test site where you can test code first before making changes to your live site

Comment: @arun: no, "WSOD" doesn't load anything - no login, just nothing.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yes, I realize now what I did to be a mistake. I was trying to add a shortcode to the theme.

Comment: I think the best solution here is to speak to your hosting company and see if they can maybe help you to delete the code or something like that. Apart from that, there is nothing I can do for you

Comment: Adding to Pieter's suggestion, ask support to move your whole theme folder outside `/themes`, this way WP will revert to a default theme.

Comment: Create a file called php.ini, put "display_errors=1" in it, and upload to your root directory.

You should now be able to see what error is causing the white page.